# UWP Application not run correctly on startup

Tags: uwp, startup, messagedialog

I used the following code to set up and test the startup, but when I reset the computer, my project is displayed below, and even my Message-Dialog is not displayed

[[Article Source : Configure your app to start at log-in](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/)]

I use these codes : [Code Source : Test Startup](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/TestStartup)

I wanted to attach my code but an error occurred that you have to write a description!

My code is similar to the link above, only I show a Message-Dialog on `public MainPage()`, that's all.

[image: UWP Application not run correctly on startup]

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work, again like before, the project opens like the picture above and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849201/11428278), my problem was solved, I copied the code in the above link to the `App.xaml` file and the problem was solved :)

[image]